# Multiple waitOn in iron-router not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I have a global waitOn that subcribes to a cart publication.

However on the cart page I want to show the list of items in the cart, the cart has a line_items array of objects with listingIds.

So I need to subscribe to the listings on the cart page as well to show them.

Here's what I have so far

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: "layout",
    loadingTemplate: "loading",
    waitOn: function(){
        if(Session.get("cartId"))
            return Meteor.subscribe("cart", Session.get("cartId"));
    }
});
```

Cart route

```
this.route("cart", {
    path: "/cart",
    waitOn: function(){
        if(Session.get("cartId")){
            var line_items = Carts.findOne(Session.get("cartId")).line_items;
            var ids = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < line_items.length; i++){
                ids.push(line_items[i].listingId);
            }
            return Meteor.subscribe("cartItems", ids);
        }

    }
});
```

I'm getting the error Cannot read property 'line_items' of undefined. I think this is happening because it's trying to subscribe before the cart subscription.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: You may find [this post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your waitOn function has the assumption that `Carts.findOne(Session.get("cartId"))` always returns something.

Initially when Meteor loads your data will not be ready and you need to account for that. You need to check that the cart exists in the first place.

```
var cart = Carts.findOne(Session.get("cartId"))

if(!cart) return false;

var line_items = cart.line_items;
```

While i'm not sure about the way you're using the waitOn handlers as the return value must always be the subscription you will also need to deal with what to do if the above `Carts.findOne()` returns null and if `Session.get("cartId")` is `null` too.

Comment: Changing it to if(Session.get("cartId") && cart) worked perfectly, thanks!